# Iphone 5s wifi not showing

Tags: iphone

The WiFi in my iPhone has stopped working. I tried turning it off and on, and resetting the network but it didn't work. Also my WiFi at home is fine so I think it's the iPhone.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I had the same problem. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208775/latest-ios-9-doesnt-show-wifi-symbol-even-when-connected-to-wifi Turn it off & on.

Comment: The OP already tried turning it off and on apparently.